# How to add filename from sql table to a path?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of many .BAK files in some directory "c:/backups/" and I want to restore all files, using command `restore verify only from disk ="path"+@filename`

where @filename is .BAK file fetched from database in a loop.

But I am getting the syntax error `"Invalid syntax near +"`
How to append @filename after the path?

Comment: why tag `mysql` and `sql-server` at the same time

Comment: @SomeVariable = 'path'+@filename and then use it in your statement

Comment: 1st Tag only the DBMS you are using, 2nd show us the code you run.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of guess work, due to the OP not providing their RDBMS, or their code.

Anyway, my guess is that they are using SQL Server and are attempting to do a statement along the lines of:

```
DECLARE @FilePath varchar(255) = 'C:\Backups\';
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase] TO DISK @FilePath + 'MyDatabase.bak';
```

Simply put, this won't work; you can't pass an expression to the `BACKUP` statement. You can only a variable or a literal string. Thus you would need to do something like:

```
DECLARE @FilePath varchar(255) = 'C:\Backups\';
DECLARE @FullPath varchar(255) = @FilePath + 'MyDatabase.bak';
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase] TO DISK @FullPath;
```

Comment: thanks @lamu!
but i had tried that, it isnt working out

Comment: @abhishekyadav *"it isn't working"*? Also La**RN**u. ;)

Comment: Also @abhishekyadav you haven't actually updated your post to show your tried SQL, or the correct RDBMS. You should be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @BackupPath NVARCHAR(255) = 'c:/backups/'
DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(255) = 'YourDatabaseName' + '.bak'

DECLARE @Restore NVARCHAR(1024) = 'restore verifyonly from disk = ' + CHAR(39) + @BackupPath + @DatabaseName + CHAR(39)

SELECT @Restore
```

You just need to alter the 'YourDatabaseName' part to match what you need. The select is there to show you the sample output of:

`restore verifyonly from disk = 'c:/backups/YourDatabaseName.bak'`